# Bootstrap 4 Nav bar larger than viewport

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a bootrstrap 4 website with a fixed-top navbar.
All works fine except when i open the site with a smartphone or with the device mode in Google Chrome Development Tools, the page has the navbar that overflows right and if i reduce the zoom i have a page like in the following picture.

[image: Website picture]

This is my navbar code and i import it on all the pages through php include:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/navbar-brand.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mcnMenu" aria-controls="mcnMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Apri/Chiudi menu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mcnMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/teamspeak"><i class="fab fa-teamspeak"></i> TeamSpeak</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/server" id="serverDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-server"></i> Servers</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="serverDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/testworld">TestWorld</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/youtube"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> YouTube</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/redcraft"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> RedCraft</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/contatti"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i> Contatti</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Am i doing something wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'am affraid your snippet is not working

Comment: Could be a few things, make a fiddle to reproduce it..

Comment: I don't know if i'm using fiddle correctly (i've never used it) https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/72100/. But i don't think this can be reproduced by a fiddle so this is the url to the site https://www.loreschaeffer.it

Comment: Your fiddle looks like it is working correctly. What is different between the two (besides using Bootstrap 3 in fiddle)?

Comment: Nothing, they are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be with the other sections in your code and, not in the navbar (As your jsfiddle working fine). Therefore, Check inspect using your browser's developer tool to find the issue.(Specially check your carousel section.). **And also don't forget to clean the browser cache**. Check the attached Image. [image]

Comment: I figured out that the banner is causing the problem, now I'm using the class '.img-fluid' from bootstrap to make the image responsive instead of css 'width: 100%;'